# Why is my search url so ugly?

Tags: wordpress, url, search, google-custom-search

I have a wordpress blog with google custom search engine (paid version) installed (2 page format).  I'm trying to figure out why searches result in very ugly URLs.

If you search for "lion", you get http://nagonline.net/search-results/?q=lion&submit=Search+nagonline.net#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=lion&gsc.page=1

Why don't I get: http://nagonline.net/search-results/?q=lion

Where is all that extra cruft coming from?

Thanks,
CB

Comment: There just isn't enough information here to adequately answer your question (ie code)...

Comment: do you use google custom search?